# Mage::getBaseUrl() vs Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)

Tags: magento-1.7, url, performance, base-url

Is there a reason to use `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)` rather than `Mage::getBaseUrl()`? I've seen both in use, and they both return the same thing. Is the longer one redundant? It uses 2 function calls, as well.

Moreover, I see that `Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB` simply returns the string 'web'. What's the point of it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First look at `getBaseUrl()` at `Mage.php`

```
 public static function getBaseUrl($type = Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)
    {
        return self::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl($type, $secure);
    }
```

In a simple word we can  say:

`Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)` indicated Your Magento `Site Url` from `this url Magento is running it System`.

And other word ,we can say  that `Mage::getBaseUrl() give the url which is linking your magento internal page urls That MVC page`

**Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB):**

**Value Set at** : From  `Admin>System>Configuration>WebSite>Secure/Unsecure -> Base url`

**Mage::getBaseUrl():**

**Value Set at** : From  `Admin>System>Configuration>WebSite>Secure/Unsecure -> Base Link url`

### Main Difference Showing:

Whenever we are enable `Use Web Server Rewrites = no` from  `admin>system>Web>Search Engines Optimization Rewrites`

`Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)` give the value of `http://youdomain/`

but  `Mage::getBaseUrl()` give value  `http://youdomain/index.php/` that actually give the value of  `Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK`

when you `hit http://youdomain/` that is call `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)`  url 
 But that `times you can see all page`link of  your `site is 
starting with http://youdomain/index.php/`  that means it taken `Mage::getBaseUrl()/ Mage::getBaseUrl($type = Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)`

**Example:**

If you have create a folder `amit at Magento root dir  and there you have put a file test.js` then you want to call this file at magento home then you can use this code

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'amit/test.js'; ?>
```

and it give then url

```
www.yourdomain/amit/test.js
```

If You use only `Mage::getBaseUrl()` which give u 
`www.yourdomain/index.php/amit/test.js` that mean test.js cannot accessible (when rewite disable)

But you have create  new controller and new action then you can use

```
Mage::getBaseUrl().'yourmodulerouter/yourcontroller/youraction'

it show  url like `http://yourdomain/index.php/yourmodulerouter/yourcontroller/youraction`
```

or give `http://yourdomain/yourmodulerouter/yourcontroller/youraction`(when rewrite enable)

Comment: So `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)` will work better when we have rewrites turned on?

Comment: no.Mage::getBaseUrl():is always use for magento pageliks

Comment: Thanks for helping. But you said that `Mage::getBaseUrl()` gives you a link that has `index.php` in it. Why would I want that extra index.php if I don't need it?

Comment: If i send do  not send any parameter  on function getBaseUrl() then it send if params as  $type = Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)

Comment: pleas check this magento Mage.php

Comment: @AmitBera I am not sure if this is correct. getBaseUrl() return in my case http://dev.magento18.com/default/ while Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_DIRECT_LINK) returns http://dev.magento18.com/