# problems getting base url (throws exception)

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, full-page-cache

i'm trying to get the base URL within Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor (line 206)-- however, i'm running into the above error. Any work around that doesn't involve hardcoding the url directly?

```
$homepage = Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

above is what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I've not tried accessing `getBaseUrl()` - remember that FPC only instantiates a minimum amount of models (that's where the performance advantage comes from). You can't access the entire Magento god class from an FPC instantiated model.

Comment: so I'd essentially have to hardcore our base URL then, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should look at `getBaseUrl()` definition which in `app\Mage.php`.

```
public static function getBaseUrl($type = Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)
    {
        return self::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl($type, $secure);
    }
```

That means it returns site URL of your site. So first thing that you should check is whether base URL is set in backend ( `Admin > System > Configuration > WebSite > Secure/Unsecure -> Base url` )

And then ***[follow this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/magegetbaseurl-vs-magegetbaseurlmage-core-model-storeurl-type-web)***. Amit has explained it very well.