# Base url and Whatsapp button (script embed with secure and unsecure url)

Tags: base-url

I'm trying to integrate Whatsapp button on my magento website.

I added the following code to my head.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(typeof wabtn4fg==="undefined"){wabtn4fg=1;h=document.head||document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],s=document.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>js/whatsapp/whatsapp-button.js";h.appendChild(s);}</script>
```

I get the following console error when I visit secure url pages because .js url is always http://

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.mywebsite......' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://www.mywebsite..../whatsapp-button.js'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there a way to get secure base url on secure pages and unsecure base url on unsecure pages?

Comment: Try out this simple extension https://magecomp.com/magento-whatsapp-contact.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411531/magento-ssl-links

```
Mage::getUrl('', array('_secure'=>($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443?true:false)))
```

That way it will return a secure or insecure link depending on whether or not the current page is secure.

Comment: Solved with this

Comment: The `$_SERVER` bit is unnecessary. All Magento blocks (and therefore templates) have an `$this->_isSecure()` method to check if the current request is secure. You could tidy this up with `Mage::getUrl('', array('_secure'=>$this->_isSecure()))`

Answer (score 2):

Simply using a relative protocol of `//` instead of `<?php echo Mage::getBaseUr() ?>` will suffice. Or simply use HTTPS for both HTTP and HTTPS, as HTTP won't throw mixed protocol warnings.

`<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('', true) ?>`

```
 public static function getBaseUrl($type = Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)
    {
        return self::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl($type, $secure);
    }
```

- [Mage::getBaseUrl() vs Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/magegetbaseurl-vs-magegetbaseurlmage-core-model-storeurl-type-web)

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @boomer