# How to get Magento root url properly?

Tags: url, base-url, geturl

I have custom script located inside Magento root directory used for ajax call. I am wondering what would be the safest way to get proper root url, no matter which store is user currently at.

Will `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)` always show root url without index.php or store code or anything else inside url?

I made some testing and it looked fine, but maybe I missed something that will show up on one of the 1000 different stores where this will be used. This is why I am asking this question.

Tnx!

Comment: see that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/magegetbaseurl-vs-magegetbaseurlmage-core-model-storeurl-type-web/42725#42725

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you need:

```
Mage::getUrl('');
```

Comment: This is not correct, I need root url, not store url. Mage::getUrl('') will return www.domain.com/storecode and not www.domain.com

Comment: what do you mean by root url then? Root is relative to a store view.

Comment: Url of folder where index.php file is located. If I put custom.php script to Magento root, I need to find out url of this script. Mage::getUrl('')  will return www.domain.com/storecode but index.php is inside www.domain.com and not inside www.domain.com/storecode/

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL);
```

Should do it and always give you the url without Index.php

Comment: Tnx but index.php is not the only worry, also store code and other things. If my custom script custom.php is inside Magento root and if user has multidomain store using the same Magento instance. I need to make sure that in such case Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL)."/custom.php" will always call custom.php script.

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes I tried in my store and it works, I just want to make sure it will work also on other 1000+ stores with different store configurations :)

Comment: It should in my opinion :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will help you: Mage::getBaseUrl();